# Asp menu - set visible dependents  on authentication

Tags: asp.net

How do I set asp:menu **node** visible dependents on authentication (not on roles)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After authentication we generally have sessions to check is it a proper authentication or not. So on the basis of session you hide show menu.

Like

```
If(Session["MySession"]== null)
{
     aspmenu.visible= false;
}
else
{
   aspmenu.visible =true;
}
```